# windows exe author information and properties

Tags: windows, exe

How can I set the windows author information and properties of a made exe file? So that when you right click -- properties it it will show all that information.

Basically after the exe file is made/compiled, which I am doing by and through lua btw.

Thanks.

Comment: Any use for you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365522(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: No, its not a c program. I can't add those things in it.